# Enable C++ Modules TS in clang-cl

Tags: c++, clang, c++-modules, clang-cl

I am using clang (from LLVM version 7.00) on Windows via `clang-cl`.

I am trying to get C++ Modules to work. I have tried the clang command line arguments `-fmodules-ts` and `-fmodules`.

I have also tried the `msvc` command line arguments (which work under MSVC - I am using 15.8.5) `/experimental:module /module:interface` (which would be the normal way for non-experimental options).

All options result in the error `clang-cl.exe: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl`.

Anyone know if it's possible to use the C++ Modules TS under `clang-cl`?

Comment: Have you checked `clang-cl --help` and `man clang-cl` whether it lists those options?

Comment: @MartinUeding given that clang-cl will pass any unrecognised commandline argument through to the clang backend, I don't see how this helps.

Comment: You could try `build2`. I wrote a [tiny preprocessor](https://github.com/aaron-michaux/mobius) for the `ninja` build system that has a modules-ts example. I've only tried it on Ubuntu. If you can read bash, then you should be able to adapt it to windows.

Comment: @Zendel, or I could just write my own compiler :-) Unfortunately clang-cl is a strange beast (clang it ain't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [option `-Xclang`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-xclang), like this:

```
clang-cl -Xclang -fmodules
```

Comment: Have you already used this? It accepts the option but does not seem to actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

To enable C++ modules support you will need latest clang 10.0 release (suspect so), that one can be downloaded from this URL, as latest snapshot build:

```
https://llvm.org/builds/
```

With Visual studio 2019 / windows - checkout following git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/NTSFka/CMakeCxxModules.git
```

Open folder with Visual studio 2019, from Configuration > Managed configurations

Add x64-CLang-Debug configuration, select it.

Check "Show advanced variables" and in `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` select

```
C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
```

and from `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` select

```
C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe
```

Compile program.

What I have tested by myself intellisense works, but still some text is displayed in red color (vs2019, 16.3.7), situation might change with Visual studio updates.